Trouble getting NODRIVER to display the requested webpage
I have been using selenium for some time, but am starting to run into various security systems which make automated browsing difficult. I have read about NODRIVER and am experimenting. I have several questions

Where is the best place to go to learn how to use it along with asyncio - it seems to me the two have to go hand in hand.

I'd like to maximize the size of the window, but i can't seem to find any way that is built into NODRIVER.

I am trying to bring up a browser and then access a website.Using the code below (i have created a mini version of the code in question)  i sometimes get access to the page and other times the browser just sits there and then the whole thing shuts down leaving the message that follows.  I am not sure, but i am guessing that something timed out and that generated the error messages.
Code Follows:
import nodriver as uc
  import asyncio
     import pyautogui
     from time import sleep

     login_page_url ="https://www.youtube.com/"

     async def start_chrome_and_log_in():
         print("starting chrome")
         # start a new Chrome instance
         driver = await uc.start()
         #   Force window to maximum size - crude method - fix someday
         pyautogui.click(x=1181, y=38)
         # visit the target website
         sleep(5)
         print("accessing webpage")
         page = await driver.get("https://www.mediterraliving.com/Club/Login")
         print("back from webpage load")


     asyncio.run(start_chrome_and_log_in())



Error Block follows:
Exception ignored in: <function BaseSubprocessTransport.del at 0x0000016061ADD080>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\MyStuff\Travels\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 126, in del
File "C:\MyStuff\Travels\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 104, in close
File "C:\MyStuff\Travels\Python312\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 109, in close
File "C:\MyStuff\Travels\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 772, in call_soon
File "C:\MyStuff\Travels\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 519, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
I'd appreciate any help that someone can provide. Thanks in advance...

If you don't fix this example so that it becomes a minimal reproducible example, it is likley you are never getting any answers here. Please, fix the identation, add the missing imports and declarations. (What is "uc", for example?) .
As it is, the code is in a state of "not even wrong",  and people won't step in to answer.
